# Spacing between units in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I am using the siunitx package and the documentation is a bit mind-blowing.

I'm using it with no options and no sisetup.

There is zero spacing my units. I have tried to add sisetup with inter-unit-product = \, but there is no change. I believe this is meant to be the default anyway.

Here is an example.

[image: Example of badly spaced units]

For example, I use `\unit{\J \kg^{-1} \K^{-1}}` to typeset the corresponding unit.

Any help in getting some spacing between these units is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You can't go wrong with `\unit{\joule\per\kilogram\per\kelvin}`.

Comment: It seems both `\unit{\J . \kg^{-1} . \K^{-1}}` and `\unit{\J \per\kg \per\K}` inserts (value of) `inter-unit-product` between units.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package has two ways of reading units. First, you can give all units as commands:

```latex
\unit\unit{\J\per\kg\per\K}
```

This is parsed, and is used to construct the output with controllable formatting. Second, you can use 'literal' mode, where things are given by yu and typeset 'as is', e.g.

```latex
\unit\unit{J.kg^{-1}.K^{-1}}
```

In this mode, inter-unit spaces are indicated by `.` or `~`.

You have mixed the two, using unit macros but some literal formatting. That forces the literal mode, but as you have no inter-unit spaces indicated, you get none. Either add `.` between units

```latex
\unit\unit{\J.\kg^{-1}.\K^{-1}}
```

or swtich to full macro-based units.

Comment: I have plans for a 'free text' mode,but that would still not work for the origianl input. 'Free text' wold be more `J per kg per K`/`joule per kilogram per kelvin`.

Comment: Thank you @JosephWright. This worked. Can I ask you a question somewhat unrelated? Is the siunitx package documentation complete? I see everywhere people use a macro SI{}{} for numbers and units, but I haven't seen this mentioned in the docs and a search doesn't find it. Is the stuff on literal and parsing differences in there too?

Comment: @LostInHilbertSpace Docs do mention `\SI` but only briefly: it was the v1/v2 interface, but I changed it for v3. For the vast majority of cases it works the same as `\qty`. The literal and parsed units are also covered.